# Adding default value for magento2 admin form select field

Tags: magento2

I am adding a select option with below code in my form

```
$fieldset->addField(
            'is_active',
            'select',
            [
                'label' => __('Status'),
                'title' => __('Status'),
                'name' => 'is_active',
                'required' => true,
                'options' => ['1' => __('Enabled'), '0' => __('Disabled')]

            ]
        );
```

Now I need to add default value as 'Enabled'. Adding below line not helping.

```
'value' => '1'
```

I checked in vendor/magento/framework/Data/Form/Element/Select.php, below code ( line #57) is having empty value.

```
$value = $this->getValue();
```

Dont know if I am missing something. Can someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code. Hope this will help you.

```
$fieldset->addField(
    'is_active', 
    'select',
    array(
        'label' => __("Status"),
        'class' => 'required-entry',
        'required' => 'true',
        'name' => 'is_active',        
        'value' => 1,
        'values'    => [
            ['label' => 'Enabled', 'value' => 1],
            ['label' => 'Disabled', 'value' => 0]
        ]
    )
);
```

Comment: 'value' => '1',
                'values'    => array(
                    array('label' => 'Enabled', 'value' => '1'),
                    array('label' => 'Disabled', 'value' => '0')
                )
working now!

Answer (score 0):

Ronak Parmars code is correct however syntax problems. I dont have the Rep to comment so I have posted the correct copy.

```
    $fieldset->addField(
             'is_active', 
             'select',
              array(
                   'label' => __("Status"),
                   'class' => 'required-entry',
                   'required' => 'true',
                   'name' => 'is_active',        
                   'value' => 1,
                   'values'    => array(
                         array('label' => 'Enabled', 'value' => 1),
                         array('label' => 'Disabled', 'value' => 0)
                         )
                   )
             );
```

Comment: Welcome to MSE. As you are already know that this section is for posting answer only so I encourage to follow same for next posts.