# set default value for magento2 admin form text field?

Tags: magento2, adminform

I want to set default Value Set For Magento 2 Admin Form Text Field Default Value Set.So Plz If Any Idea Help.Thanks In Advance.
`$fieldset->addField(
                'name',
                'text',
                ['name' => 'name', 
                'label' => __('Name'), 
                'title' => __('Name'), 
                'required' => true,
                ]
            );`

Comment: 'value' => __('defaultvaluehere'),

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding default value for magento2 admin form select field](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/224177/adding-default-value-for-magento2-admin-form-select-field)

Comment: You can do this by creating an config.xml  file etc folder of your module and use the field_id of the field/form column to map the value

Answer (score 0):

Try the code like this one :

```
$fieldset->addField(
                'name',
                'text',
                ['name' => 'name', 
                'label' => __('Name'), 
                'title' => __('Name'), 
                'required' => true,
                'value' => 'your default value' 
                ]
);
```

Comment: Just a doubt. Does that values be rewritten afterwards?

Comment: Yes, you can edit when you add or edit the record.

Comment: Not Working Try

Comment: which issue you are facing?

Comment: Default Value Not Set In Admin Form Using Above Code